# Function in C language. + Arrays

Tags: c

I faced a problem which I'm not able to solve by my own.

I have to write a function that returns 0 if the array is a downward sequence, otherwise, the number of the first number that violates the pattern. Use this function in an application that asks the user an integer N and an array of N numbers.

But i don't have a clue how to do it!

There is my code.

```
int *AnotherArray;
int i;
int Length;

system("cls");
printf("\t\t put Array volume: ");
scanf("%d", &Length);
printf("\n\n");

AnotherArray = (int*)malloc(Length * sizeof(int));

for (i = 0; i<Length; i++)
{
    printf("\t [%d] Елемент масиву = ", i);
    scanf("%d", &AnotherArray[i]);
}
printf("\n\n");

printf("\tYour Array: ");

for (i = 0; i<Length; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", AnotherArray[i]);
}
for(i=1; i<Length; i++)

    if(AnotherArray[i-1]>AnotherArray[i])
    {
        printf("\t(From up to down!)\n");
        break;
    }
for(i=1; i<Length; i++)
    if (AnotherArray[i-1]<AnotherArray[i])
    {

        printf("\t(From down to up!)\n");
        break;
    }
for(i=1; i<Length; i++)
    if (AnotherArray[i-1]==AnotherArray[i])
    {
        printf("\t(All numbers are equal!)\n");
        break;
    }

printf("\t\t\n downward sequence stop there: ");
printf("  %d", AnotherArray[0]);

for (i = 0; i<Length; i++)
{
    for (i = 0; AnotherArray[i]>AnotherArray[i+1]; i++)
    {
        printf("  %d", AnotherArray[i+1]);
    }

    printf("\t\t\n upward sequence stop there: ");
    printf("  %d", AnotherArray[0]);

    for (i = 0; i<Length; i++)
    {
        for (i = 0; AnotherArray[i]<AnotherArray[i+1]; i++)
        {
            printf("  %d", AnotherArray[i+1]);
        }
        free(AnotherArray);
        printf("\n\n\t Press 'ENTER' to back to the menu\n");
        getch();
        {
            main();
        }
        return 0;
 }
```

Comment: "For every element in the array [0..n), if the current element value is larger than [or equal, depending on exact interpretation] the previous element then the 'downward sequence' is violated at the current element value/index." -- not quite sure why there is upward/downward/rightward code shown; although the same principal holds.

Comment: I don't have a clue how to solve this thing. But this task have to be done till tomorrow...

Comment: The above mostly does that.. it needs to have the "is downward" to be turned into a function.. there is lots of extra code that is muddling up the task.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. While I feel sympathy for the predicament you are in, the urgency of your problem is of no concern on this site. This is supposed to be a repository of QA that is as much as possible timeless.

Comment: May you help me with solving this?

Comment: You need to ask a specific problem. " i don't have a clue how to do it" is off-topic here. Ask an on-point, on-topic problem with full description of the issue and a [MCVE] and we will gladly help. This site is not for fishing in the dark.

Comment: Ok, I do not know how to make this function "function that returns 0 if the array is a downward sequence, otherwise, the number of the first number that violates the pattern. Use this function in an application that asks the user an integer N and an array of N numbers." properly. Thats why I'm here, asking for help, asking someone to show me how it have to be done.

Comment: so you basically have a code that works and you want to convert it into a function? Is that correct? Is is really not clear that's what you are asking from the question. Please [edit] your question to be more clear.

Comment: This code doesnt work how it have to. It have to work in way i described in the body of the question. But in my code it doesnt work in such way.

Comment: Two points to note 1) your "equal values" loop should check for inequality, not equality. If at the end of the loop `i == Length` then they were all equal. 2) do not call `main()`, simply `return` back to where you called the function in `main().`

Comment: @Vgeorgy you need to show the observable behavior of your code. Please [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: @WeatherVane , may you make it and sent me the code please? Because I'm too stupid to fix it by my own. I would appreciate you)

Comment: Just change the test from `==` to `!=` and the message. It's very much like the first two tests. Then after the loop, check the iterator to know whether the loop completed, or had a `break`. Your C book will tell you how to make a function.

Comment: for(i=1; i<Length; i++)
    if (AnotherArray[i-1]!=AnotherArray[i])
    {
        printf("\t(All numbers are equal!)\n");
        break;
    }              Like this?

Comment: You have to change the message too. Plainly if you changed the test from `==` to `!=` you have to change the message too. This means adding a "not" into that message. `printf("\t(All numbers are not equal!)\n");` Note: you can't test if they are all equal by breaking the loop at the first equality. But you *can* test if they are not all equal by breaking the loop at the first inequality.

Comment: So as i get it in this case everything should be alright, isn't it? I'm asking about it because i can't check it now. Thats why i ask for code.

Comment: Here is skeleton code for the function. Replace all three `...` with code. The function does not need to be bigger than that. https://pastebin.com/PjFJ2fnE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to do your homework for you. However, I know that it sometimes helps to see a working example. This is a really super rudimentary example, but it should help you to understand the logic behind such a problem.

Please study this answer, rather than just submitting it as correct. You will only gain insight by learning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


const int asc = 1;
const int desc = 0;

int array_asc[11] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int array_desc[11] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
int array_rand[11] = {7,3,8,4,5,1,6,2,4,4};

int order_check[2] = {0, 0};

int check_order(int* array){

    if(array[0] < (array[1])){
        order_check[0] = asc;
    } else if (array[1] < (array[0])){
        order_check[0] = desc;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int check_array(int* array, int* check){


    switch(check[0]){

        case 1: 
        for(int i = array[0]; i < array[9]; i ++){
            if(array[i] < (array[i+1])){
                continue;
            } else {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }; break;

        case 0: 
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if(array[i] > (array[i+1])){
                continue;
            } else {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }; break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int ret;

    if(check_order(array_rand) == 0){
        if(ret = check_array(array_rand, order_check)){
            printf("Order breaks at index %d", ret);
        } else {
            printf("Array is in perfect order");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Array is not in order.\n");
    }    
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```